# What is the LDS line of authority should a Bishop be unavailable?

Tags: lds, priesthood, authority

**I am seeking a complete and authoritative explanation of this issue.**

Who presides at Sacrament meeting (common Sunday services) when the bishop of a ward (pastor of a local congregation) is unavailable?  There are several circumstances that should be considered when answering this question.  The best answer will cite both the handbook of instructions and scripture to justify the explanation.  Linking back to Church resources is appreciated.

- **When any higher authority is easily accessible and...**

  - When the Bishop (perhaps due to illness) is suddenly unavailable.
  - When the entire bishopric is unavailable, but the absence was expected.
  - When the entire bishopric is unavailable, but the absence was unexpected.
- **When all higher authorities are also unavailable and...**

  - When the Bishop (perhaps due to illness) is suddenly unavailable.
  - When the entire bishopric is unavailable, but the absence was expected.
  - When the entire bishopric is unavailable, but the absence was unexpected.

*A bonus would be an explanation of what priesthood keys (or priesthood authority) is NOT available when any or all of these circumstances take place.  As an example (and as a hint), if the bishop and all higher authorities are unavailable, non-priesthood disciplinary councils cannot be convened.*

Comment: I think there are two separate questions here: 1) Who should preside at sacrament meeting, and 2) What meetings or activities require the bishop to be present. Presiding at sacrament meeting (or any meeting, like a Relief Society meeting, or Sunday School presidency meeting) does not require priesthood keys; but authorizing the sacrament to be administered does. The sacrament can be administered without anyone presiding, if authorized by someone who holds keys.

Comment: I agree with @SamuelBradshaw.  The bonus should be a separate question if the OP really wants a comprehensive answer (rather than just for the ordinance of the sacrament), as is suggested by his example of disciplinary councils.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The policy for who presides at sacrament meeting is found in [Handbook 2, 18.2](https://www.lds.org/handbook/handbook-2-administering-the-church/meetings-in-the-church?lang=eng#182)*:

> The bishop oversees ward meetings. He presides at these meetings
>   unless a member of the stake presidency, an Area Seventy, or a General
>   Authority attends. His counselors may conduct ward meetings and may
>   preside if he is absent. Presiding authorities and visiting high
>   councilors should be invited to sit on the stand. High councilors do
>   not preside when attending ward meetings.
>
> If the bishop and his counselors are all absent, the stake president
>   designates who presides at sacrament meeting. Normally he designates
>   the elders quorum president, but he could authorize another
>   priesthood holder instead.

So, if the bishop is absent, his counselors preside. In practice, this usually means the first counselor, and if he is absent, it is the second counselor. If neither the bishopric nor his counselors are present, whoever the stake president designates will preside.

If the entire bishopric is unexpectedly gone and the stake presidency is unreachable to designate who will preside, then circumstances are extraordinary and chances are that a normal sacrament meeting would not be held.

The sacrament can only be administered with authorization from the bishop (who holds [priesthood keys](https://www.lds.org/new-era/2012/05/priesthood-keys?lang=eng) for ordinances like baptism and the sacrament within his ward boundaries), or the stake president, who holds similar keys within his stake. The bishop may authorize a priesthood holder to administer the sacrament in his ward boundaries, outside of a formal sacrament meeting. Nobody presides per se at these informal sacrament services, but the person who the bishop designates conducts (see 18.2.2 in the Handbook chapter linked above).

---

*Prior to April 2019, when this answer was originally written, the quote from Handbook 2 referenced the "high priests group leader" instead of the elders quorum president. The high priests group leader position [no longer exists as of April 2018](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/2018/04/the-elders-quorum?lang=eng), so the quote has been updated to reflect the newer wording in Handbook 2.

Comment: Your answre is incomplete if it doesn't deal with D&C 20:44,49,56 etc.

Comment: Those verses don't talk about presiding, only conducting. When an elder is called upon [by the presiding authority] to conduct a meeting, this is how they should do it ("as they are led by the Holy Ghost, according to the commandments and revelations of God"). Many of the things mentioned in these verses (baptize, ordain to priesthood offices, administer the sacrament, and confirm new members), despite them being responsibilities of the office, are things the elder only does when called upon or authorized by the bishop.

Comment: That distinction would have improved your answer.

Comment: Asking it in a separate question might yield better results. This is a great answer to the question also read it (ignoring the bonus).

Comment: For clarity, the Bishop *does not* authorize priesthood holders to administer the sacrament, the authority is a part of the mantle of the priesthood that priests hold. The bishop is responsible for *directing* the administration of the sacrament. We had a bishop recently correct us on this verbiage during a lesson.

Comment: "Authorize" is the word used in Handbook 2 (18.2.2) when talking about administering the sacrament outside of sacrament meeting. See also "How to Perform Ordinances" here, which also uses the term "authorize" for the bishop: https://www.lds.org/manual/duties-and-blessings-of-the-priesthood-basic-manual-for-priesthood-holders-part-b/priesthood-and-church-government/lesson-5-performing-priesthood-ordinances?lang=eng

Comment: @ShemSeger That's not right because the bishop is the president of the priest quorum. In that role he holds the keys to the sacrament.

Comment: @kutschkem The emphasis was that the bishop does not give them *authority* to perform the sacrament, he gives them *permission* to perform the ordinance.

Comment: You're right, the authority and the permission come from separate sources. That's good to point out.

Comment: @ShemSeger Okay, that sounds better :-P

Comment: @ShemSeger, regrettably, in English "to authorize" is identical to "to grant permission."  Thus, the Church's use of "authorize" in the official documents.  The true separation is the difference between having keys and not having keys.  Priests have the power to bless the Sacrament, but they do not have the key to authorize the ordinance (held by the Bishop).  Which makes the issue one of semantics.  It's like being trained to drive a car but the state refuses to give you a license.  Call that training what you will, without the license from an authority you can't legally drive the car.

Comment: Very similarly, Roman Catholicism differentiates between invalid actions that have no spiritual affect whatsoever (e.g. a bishop trying to ordain a woman to the priesthood) and *illicit* actions that are within the actor's spiritual power but are not authorized by the discipline of the church (e.g. a bishop ordaining a priest outside of his jurisdiction, or a priest or bishop performing nearly any sacramental act after being formally defrocked). Illicit actions actually do take place from a sacramental perspective, but those knowingly taking part in them are gravely sinning and *in trouble*.